# Azure Active Directory not redirecting to GoDaddy for password

Tags: authentication, active-directory, microsoft-edge

My company uses GoDaddy for our mail and Active Directory will redirect to it when I want to log into Outlook. When I sign out of Outlook, I get the two message boxes "hold on while ...." and "it's a good idea to close ...". Signing in again to Outlook redirects me to GoDaddy and requires me to enter my password.

That's all to be expected.

I have an application that uses Active Directory for authentication. When I log in, I am redirected to GoDaddy.

When I log out, I get the message boxes and then I get the Logout URL SamlResponse saying the logout has been successful.

But when I log in again, I am asked to select my email account but I am not redirected to GoDaddy. Instead, I get Reply URL with the user information. As if I am still logged into Active Directory.

Even if I sign out of Azure or Outlook, I am not redirected to GoDaddy when I log into my application.

Moreover, this WAS working just a hour ago. At that time, I was redirected to GoDaddy when I logged out of my application.

One more interesting thing is the message boxes appear very quickly (I can hardly read the "hold on" message when it normally remains on the screen for a couple of seconds.)

Any hint or suggestions would be appreciated.

**UPDATE:** I have discovered that my application runs as expected in Chrome and Firefox. It is only Edge that is exhibiting the behavior described above

Comment: Do you have any Edge account logged in? You can try: 1. InPrivate mode. 2. Use a local profile. 3. Clear all the cookies and cache.